# Task management algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, php, scheduled-tasks, task

i am looking for efficient task management fo C#

what i mean by task management is executing pre-defined interval time of task.

Example:
task a needs to be run every 1 mins
task b needs to be run every 3 mins
task c needs to be run every 5 mins

these tasks can be added and removed in arbitary time...

And the task that i mentioned can be 100000 or more...
The task will be executed forever until it is removed...

Do u guys familiar with this kind of algorithm? I am thinking to implement in either c# or php....

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use the windows task manager?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the open-source [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) as it does everything you want.  There is really no good reason to roll your own for something like this.